# is package php5-mysql_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb compatible with mysql 5.6.24?

Tags: php, lamp

I have installed php with `sudo apt-get install php5` followed by `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` but received a warning when trying to use mysqli class:

```
mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch
```

command `php5 -i | grep -i client` returns:

```
Client API version => 5.6.24 
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r 
Client API library version => **5.6.24**
Client API header version => **5.5.41**
Client API version => 5.6.24
```

package installed is "php5-mysql_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb"

`php5 -v` returns:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2015 20:47:39)
```

if relevant `mysql -V` returns:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for Linux (x86_64)
```

I am fairly new to LAMP so if anyone could please be so kind as to let me know if I installed the wrong version of something I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks